# Sender Profiles not Selectable

Tags: marketing-cloud, sender-authentication-package

I have in my MC instance SAP already enabled. So my subdomain delegation is done and I can define new Sender Profiles using some "xxx@mysubdomain.domain.com" virtual email addresses. When entering these email addressses the system showed the "Verified" label properly, so apparently this new sender profile is ready to be used in the  Test Sends. But when going to perform a Test Send, these Sender Profiles are not enabled to be selected. Do you know what could be the reason for that ? any missing configuration pending to be done ? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Do you see the Sender Profile in the DropDown menu? Did you tie to a Send Classification along with a Delivery Profile?

Comment: Are they verified? Do you have the rights to select them?

Comment: Initially they are verified, but If I try to define a new Send Classification, I am not able to select the new Sender Profile. How can I see if I have the rights to select them ? Thanks !

Comment: After defining a sender profile you also need to create a send classification. otherwise you won't be able to see that under send preview sending options. :) as sender profile is not an option to select but a send classification is.

Comment: Thanks All. I found the issue. It was that the virtual email addresses being created are added to the From Address list and by default they are not sendable. You need to mark them as Sendable. Once they are sendable, the Sender Profiles are selectable.

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you mark them as Sendable?